# Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined - Google App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I've started Javascript a week ago and I'm stuck and desperate. I have this quite straightforward code (ideally when I call it it would do: =findAudience(A1) -> if in cell A1, you find an audience name please return it in the cell)(the audience names list being found in the 'list of Dimension' tab row1, column1)

My code bellow:

```
function findAudience(adSet){   
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();    
    var listSheet = ss.getSheetByName("List of Dimensions");   
    var list = listSheet.getRange(1, 1, listSheet.getLastRow().getValues();    
    var adsetsAudiences = "" ;   

    for(j = 0; j < list.length; j++){

        if(adSet.indexOf(list[j][0]) > -1 && list[j][0] != ""){

            if(adsetsAudiences != ""){
                adsetsAudiences = adsetsAudiences+", "+list[j][0]

            }else{
                adsetsAudiences = list[j][0]
            }
        }
    }

    return adsetsAudiences;
};
```

The error I get, is:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "indexOf" of undefined. (line 10, file "findAudience")

Hope this makes more sense to you than it does to me...

Thanks a loooooot in advance for having a look,

Comment: How are you calling your `findAudience()` function? Are you passing the expected parameter `adSet`? When JavaScript talks about `"undefined"` it means something has an unexpected value, or doesn't really have a value.

Comment: show output of `console.log(adset)` before `if(adSet.indexOf(list[j][0])..`

Comment: In my Gsheet, I'm going to write =findAudience(adset) adsets being found in column A.

Comment: No output... when I log it: "No logs found. Use Logger API to add logs to your project."

Comment: What's in A1? `indexOf` should be called on a array. A1 is a string and you can't directly run the function from the script editor. Call it from the sheet

Comment: I have no idea why but when I deleted the 40K rows under my list of audiences, the function start working.... Anyway thanks a lot for looking into it :)

Comment: @TheMaster Hey It's the idea yes, in A1:A there is a name that is supposed to contain an audience (all those names don't have a proper naming convention though).

Unfortunately every time I run the function I get the same error message about my "indexOf" not being defined. However, the function as a formula takes ages to load but is working. If you guys have a better idea on how to solve this issue, I'll take it! basically I'd love to do a:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("items from a range", A1)), "return the correct item from the range", "Unknown audience")

Comment: What's wrong with `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("items from a range", A1)), "return the correct item from the range", "Unknown audience")`? Why do you want to replicate this ina custom function?

Comment: @TheMaster this doesnt work on a range, it had to be either a cell or a string... Cant be a range.

Comment: Try enclosing the formula in `ARRAYFORMULA()`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `adSet` you passing into the function is not defined.

You can prevent errors of this by check the parameter early in the function:

```
function findAudience(adSet){
    if(adset === null) return false; // however you want to handle that
    // ...
}
```